# Generating Noise in Cells - CPP and GLSL

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, glsl, shader

I have code aiming to create something similar to this image.
https://thebookofshaders.com/edit.php#12/cellnoise-01.frag

In my implementation I am dividing my image to an 8x8 grid, aiming to achieve a similar effect.  After debugging I am struggling to figure out why my points draw in each cell, but every other point around them is white and does not change with distance. Note there are 64 unique points in the grid (they haven't been randomized yet, but there is one per cell).

Here is my main method:

```
uniform ivec2 u_Dimensions;
uniform int u_Time;

in vec2 fs_UV;

out vec3 color;

void main()
{

//divide the image into a grid

float xpos = (fs_UV.x * u_Dimensions.x);
float ypos = (fs_UV.y * u_Dimensions.y);

float width = float(u_Dimensions.x);
float height = float(u_Dimensions.y);

float cell_height = u_Dimensions.y / 8.f;
float cell_width = u_Dimensions.x / 8.f;

//arrays to contain the x and y for each placed point

float px[64];
float py[64];

int p_count = 0;

for(float i = 0; i < u_Dimensions.y; i+= cell_height){
    for(float j = 0; j < u_Dimensions.x; j+= cell_width){

        px[p_count] = int(j + cell_width / 5.f);    //x and y
        py[p_count] = int(i + cell_height / 2.f);   //placed manually for now

        p_count++;
    }
}


int cellx = int(float(xpos / cell_width));
int celly = int(float(ypos / cell_height));
int index = (cellx) + (8 * celly);

for(int i = 0; i < 64; i++){

    if (px[i] == int(xpos) && py[i] == int(ypos)){
        color = vec3(0, 0, 0);
        break;                      //all dots successfully draw in black

    } else {

        float close_x = (px[index]);    //these values are registering fine
        float close_y = (py[index]);

        color = vec3(255, 255, 255) / vec3(distance(vec2(xpos, ypos), vec2(close_x, close_y)));   
        //final color always appears 100% white, no gradient?
    }

}

}
```

Any help or guidance?

Comment: Full white in GLSL is `(1, 1, 1)`, not `(255, 255, 255)`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code isn't working as expected is because the valid range of values in GLSL is [0,1], however you are using a range of [0, 255] for your algorithm of voronoi cells.

As pointed out in the comments.